# AWS Kinesis Firehose to Lambda , Lambda to S3 using java

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

For my expolartion , created AWS firehose stream and configured Lambda function and  move the data to S3. Firehose to S3 it is working fine without any issue. If i enable lamda function, getting below error in S3 failed bucket.

```
{"attemptsMade":4,"arrivalTimestamp":1570727830210,"errorCode":"Lambda.FunctionError","errorMessage":"The Lambda function was successfully invoked but it returned an error result."
```

lambda java code:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + event);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (KinesisEventRecord record : event.getRecords()) {
            String payload = new String(record.getKinesis().getData().array());
            if (payload.toLowerCase().contains("scala"))
                sb.append(payload);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Basically , filter incoming streaming data and push to S3.  Also I have frw questions.
1 . i am passing punch JSON data to firehose. "record.getKinesis().getData()" method will read the record line by line and bunch to entire json string.
2. written log statment. where to check my log.
How can i handle this scenario? please advise

Comment: Lambda has the ability to pass Kinesis test events to the function.  I would try that first from the AWS console, looking closely at CloudWatch.  The nice thing about the tests in the console is that if it fails there is a nice link to the CloudWatch log.

Comment: Kinesis test event - it is wokring..since we are passing KinesisEvent object. Question is how can i pass KinesisFirehose object into Lamda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Lambda Java Events 2.x](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-events) library has support for the [KinesisFirehoseEvent](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/KinesisFirehoseEvent.java).  The 1.x library did not have this class.

Your code would look something like:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<KinesisFirehoseEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(KinesisFirehoseEvent event, Context context) {
    }
}
```

From the Lambda test environment, the event will come in looking like:

```
{
  "invocationId": "invocationIdExample",
  "deliveryStreamArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "records": [
    {
      "recordId": "49546986683135544286507457936321625675700192471156785154",
      "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1495072949453,
      "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IDEyMy4="
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.. now i am reading the data from lambda. Now i need to filter the data and send to s3.. in that case what is the return type. will string work? or any specific return type for kinesisevent . please advise

Comment: Depending on your use case you will likely want to create the S3 object within Lambda.  See, for example, [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object) for code to upload an object to S3.